# Build failed because react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated

I installed react-native-reanimated but after installing it i'm unable to run the app it keeps giving me the following error. its really frustrating. i will be really thankful if anyone could guide me.

```
/Users/rawandmajeed/Desktop/tmp/ddan/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedModule.mm:221:33: error: expected a type
/Users/rawandmajeed/Desktop/tmp/ddan/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedModule.mm:224:76: error: property 'nativeEventPath' not found on object of type '__strong id'
  eventMappingDict[@"nativeEventPath"] = RCTConvertVecToArray(eventMapping.nativeEventPath());
                                                                           ^
/Users/rawandmajeed/Desktop/tmp/ddan/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedModule.mm:226:20: error: property 'animatedValueTag' not found on object of type '__strong id'
  if (eventMapping.animatedValueTag()) {
                   ^
/Users/rawandmajeed/Desktop/tmp/ddan/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedModule.mm:227:61: error: property 'animatedValueTag' not found on object of type '__strong id'
    eventMappingDict[@"animatedValueTag"] = @(*eventMapping.animatedValueTag());
                                                            ^


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/rawandmajeed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ddan-bfgjptmiribfbdbjbkbxincjrevk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTVibration.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTVibration.o /Users/rawandmajeed/Desktop/tmp/ddan/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration/RCTVibration.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
        CompileC /Users/rawandmajeed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ddan-bfgjptmiribfbdbjbkbxincjrevk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTLinkingManager.o /Users/rawandmajeed/Desktop/tmp/ddan/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS/RCTLinkingManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)**
```

Comment: Try to remove the library again, and run `pod install`.
Then install it back again and run `pod install` in ios folder again.

Comment: I tried that many time and it didn't work it has been 2 days i tried  many things and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found out that (the new version of react-native-reanimated which is Reanimated 2 ) does not work well with react native V 0.66.0 so i change  my react native version to 0.64.0 also i changed **Flipper-Folly**,**Flipper**,**Flipper-RSocket** versions by adding this line to Podfile

```
 use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0','Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
```

after pod install

everything was okay